# TypeError: container.montage is not a function max: 300

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `Jquery` Code and it is an error

> $container.montage is not a function

I am following this [library](http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/) , and my browser is not showing any other errors. I have already checked that I am loading the required library from `FireBug` and still can't figure out what is wrong here.

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('#am-container'),
           $imgs = $container.find('img').hide(),
           totalImgs = $imgs.length,
           cnt = 0;

        $imgs.each(function(i) {
            var $img = $(this);
            $('<img/>').load(function() {
                ++cnt;
                if (cnt === totalImgs) {
                    $imgs.show();
                    $container.montage({
                        fillLastRow: true,
                        alternateHeight: true,
                        alternateHeightRange: {
                            min: 75,
                            max: 300
                        }
                    });

                    /* 
                     * just for this demo:
                     */
                    $('#overlay').fadeIn(500);
                }
            }).attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
        });

    });
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div class="main-gallary">
   <div class="container">
      <div id="am-container" class="am-container">
          <a href="#">
             <img class="ui-draggable" src="images/gallary/img-1.jpg" style="display: inline; position: relative;">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
          <a href="#">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you load the montage library before the custom script?

Comment: @NatZimmermann: yes my friend, i just wanna ask 1 thing here, does `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` allow variables to be declared like this `var $container = $('#am-container')`

Comment: Yes it does - I only learned that a few days ago but it really helps.

Comment: @NatZimmermann: Then it is what is causing the error and once i replaced it with 1.9.x it was removed.

Comment: Changing from 1.8.3 to 1.9.n will not affect the variable. Could it be that the montage plugin requires 1.9.n?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I am really not sure about this mate but when i changed the library version very thing went smooth

Comment: In a quick test in jsfiddle I found that the variable was OK - so it must have something to do with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML document you should have similar lines to the following before the rest of your code.

To load jQuery (which you probably already have):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To load the jQuery Montage Plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.montage.min.js"></script>
```

The `src="js/jquery.montage.min.js"` needs to be correct for where the file is located. Using that path you would upload it to a folder called `js` on your web-server.